# If y = (x-4)^2 in terms of x is x = y^1/2 + 4, how come the second equation produces a different graph?

Tags: calculus

I was doing calculus when I stumbled upon a problem asking for the area under a curve, I solved by searching for the area based upon the y-axis and received a completely different answer, and upon checking the graph, the second function seems to produce a completely different one than the first.

What am I missing?

Comment: $x =\pm \sqrt y+4$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that if $y=(x-4)^2$, then $x=\sqrt{y} + 4$. For example, the pair of values $x=-1, y=25$ satisfies the first equation, but it does not satisfy the second equation.